# Using a FutureBuilder to fetch a URL to render an image

Tags: flutter

I am trying to render a CircleAvatar, based on on an image URL that I fetch. The plan is to make the backgroundImage of the CircleAvatar a `CachedNetworkImageProvider`, based on the image from the URL.

```
  Future<String?> fetchProfileImageUrl() async {
    String uid = auth.currentUser?.uid ?? ""; 
    if (uid.isEmpty){ return null; }
    final profileImageRef = storage.ref().child("/users/$uid/$uid");
    try {
      final String downloadUrl = await profileImageRef.getDownloadURL();
      print("Got download URL");
      return downloadUrl;
    } 
    on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print("Could not load image: $e");
    }
  }
```

I have built a `FutureBuilder` below:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
      future: storage.fetchProfileImageUrl(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> imageUrl) {
        // print("IMAGE URL: ${imageUrl.data as String}");
      return CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: imageUrl.data as String ?? "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
          imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => 
            Container(
            child: uploadingPhoto ? SpinKitDualRing(color: primaryColor) : Column(
            children: [
              Container(
            width: 140,
            height: 120,
            child: Stack(
              children: [ 
                CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 50,
                      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      child:  CircleAvatar( radius: 48,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(imageUrl.data as String)
                                // backgroundImage: (profilePictureUrl != null) ? profilePicture?.image : AssetImage("assets/images/blank_background.png"),
                              ), 
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 5,
                  right: 25,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: secondaryColor),
                    child: Center(
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera, size: 25),
                        color: Colors.white, onPressed: () async {
                            final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 25, preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front);
                            // final photos = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: false, type: FileType.image);
                            if (pickedImage == null){ 
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                const SnackBar(content: Text("No photo picked."))
                              );
                            } else {
                              setState(() {
                                uploadingPhoto = true;
                              });
                              
                               final path = pickedImage.path;
                               final filename = pickedImage.name;
                               print(path);
                               print(filename);
                               if (path != null) {
                                  await storage.uploadPhoto(path, filename).then((value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      uploadingPhoto = false;
                                    });
                                    print("successfully uploaded");
                                });
                               }
                            }
                            
                         },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ]
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Text("anonymous", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
          placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
      );
      }
    );


  }
```

But the app crashes and returns this:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state:
_FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#49de6):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  FutureBuilder<dynamic>
  FutureBuilder:file:///Users/zorgan/Documents/test2022/lib/pages/profile.dart:49:12

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _ProfileState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:test2022/pages/profile.dart:54:35)
#1      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:616:55)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4992:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4878:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
#5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
#7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5041:11)
#8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
...     Normal element mounting (61 frames)
#69     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
#70     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
#71     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1405:37)
#72     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1390:20)
#73     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2605:19)
#74     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1382:12)
#75     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:353:23)
#76     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2246:59)
#77     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1035:15)
#78     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2246:14)
#79     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:342:5)
#80     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:428:5)
#81     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:79:12)
#82     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#83     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:149:12)
#84     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:386:11)
#85     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#86     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:516:13)
#87     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1600:12)
#88     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1507:20)
#89     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#90     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#91     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#92     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#93     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#94     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#95     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#96     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#97     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#98     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#99     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#100    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#101    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#102    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#103    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#104    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#105    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#106    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#107    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#108    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#109    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#110    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#111    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#112    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#113    _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1467:11)
#114    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#115    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#116    RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:451:14)
#117    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#118    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#119    RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:249:12)
#120    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135:7)
#121    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
#122    MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#123    _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1055:7)
#124    MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#125    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:410:14)
#126    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1973:7)
#127    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:999:18)
#128    RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:513:19)
#129    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:884:13)
#130    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:378:5)
#131    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1175:15)
#132    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1104:9)
#133    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1015:5)
#134    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:148:13)
#135    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:318:5)
#136    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: try this =>  imageUrl:( imageUrl.data ?? '') as String ?? "https://via.placeholder.com/150",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to cast imageUrl.data as String here, but you can't do that when it's null

```
imageUrl.data as String ?? "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
```

Instead, you could simply cast to nullable String like

```
imageUrl.data as String? ?? "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
```

Or better yet, tell your FutureBuilder that you are dealing with `String?` instead of `dynamic` like `FutureBuilder<String?>` (and also `AsyncSnapshot<String?>`), then you don't even need to cast and can write

```
imageUrl.data ?? "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think picked answer is wrong. the problem is in fetchProfileImageUrl function. it should return Future value instead of doing awaiting inside.

Instead of returning a String:

> final String downloadUrl = await profileImageRef.getDownloadURL();
> return downloadUrl;

it should return a Future value

> return profileImageRef.getDownloadURL();

```
Future<String?> fetchProfileImageUrl() async {

  String uid = auth.currentUser?.uid ?? "";

  if (uid.isEmpty){ return null; }
  final profileImageRef = storage.ref().child("/users/$uid/$uid");

 try {
   return profileImageRef.getDownloadURL();
 }on FirebaseException catch (e) {
  print("Could not load image: $e");
}}
```